# Sci-fi book about Earth’s first colony

Tags: story-identification, space-colonization

Not sure if one book or a series. Earth’s first colony loses touch with Earth. Without supplies they’d counted on from Earth (food, building materials, vehicles, weapons), the colonists struggle, mostly because the planet’s wildlife (plants and dinosaur-ish animals) are all deadly 24/7. The main female character is a cop, who, at the beginning, has to rescue a female friend in the badlands from a large dinosaur-ish thing.

Half-way through the book, the female cop crash lands in the middle of the deadly wilderness. The main male character, who she doesn’t like, goes to rescue her. After a week or so and lots of peril and at least one broken leg (hers), they end up getting back safely by making a canoe out of the shell of a huge animal (and in love).

The colony has major political and leadership issues, some gun-fueled, and then Earth shows up and wants to take over everything. There’s also a creepy guy who starts a brothel and a gambling establishment and schemes to be get elected the boss. Somebody starts a stampede of the dinosaur-ish wildlife down the town's main-street in the middle of the night, and also traps the main male character in his house with a big dinosuar-ish animal by blocking the door with a programmable excavating machine.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. I recommend having a look at our [guide](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) to story id questions, as it may help you to recall more details which could help narrow down the answer.

Comment: The trees could grow their roots really fast and trap and crush people in them. Maybe the animals had some kind of power beyond their tremendous strength.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of the **Donovan** series by **W Michael Gear**, I read it a few years ago.

However I no longer have any of the novels so I can't identify the particular book, hopefully this'll be enough to see which one it was.

**Update**:-
I've now downloaded book one of the series and this is the one I was thinking of, it's titled **Outpost** and the female cop is called Talina Perez